# How to draw vertical separation line between two text line android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am using two horizontal view line(id is view2 and view 3) between top and bottom of relative layout. How to place view line vertical in between two text. Here is code and screenshot of expected output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/delivery_address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address_layout"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_country"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        bold=""
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Phone: 12345678
        android:textStyle=" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_address"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#cfcfcf" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/delivery_edit_delete_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_edit"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:textColor="#555555" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delivery_edit"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_delete"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textColor="#555555" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_edit_delete_layout"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#cfcfcf" />
```

Expected output:

[image]

```
My output is:
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/delivery_address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/address_layout"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_country"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Phone: 12345678
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_address"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#cfcfcf" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/delivery_edit_delete_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="container_for_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" (Or try android:gravity)
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_edit"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

            <View
            android:id="@+id/innerLine"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cfcfcf" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" (Or try android:gravity)
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delivery_edit"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_delete"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/delivery_edit_delete_layout"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#cfcfcf" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try using a LinearLayout because that will put it right in the middle of the two. Hope this piece of code will help! I haven't tried it yet myself so you have to test it for me!

Edit : Updated to make them center (If both layout_gravity/gravity fails, try to use android:gravity in the LinearLayout).

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. i applied your code and output looks like this.http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e75394c view line is not touching above and below. it is in middle

Comment: Remove the margin from the RelativeLayout and apply it to the textviews individually. Should make it fill the boxes and will create some distance between the border and the textView.

Look at the updated coded. Gonna add some changes to make the delete and edit center.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you wish to achieve it would be best to use weights along with linear layout.
This will ensure that your vertical separator line is placed exactly in the middle of your horizontal  layout.
[Here](http://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/) is a very good post explaining the usage of weights with linear layouts.

You can refer to this code to get an idea how you can use it for your requirements.

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/delivery_edit_delete_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_edit"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cfcfcf" >
        </View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_delete"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#555555" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. still same issue. it looks like this. http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e75394ci need view to touch above and below line. view line is in middle between two textview.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code for line separator between text views.

```
<View
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:background="#979797"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a border around the textview. You do this by creating a border style in your drawables folder and then set the textview background to point to this sttyle:

```
//your textview
<TextView android:text="Hi there" android:background="@drawable/my_border/>
```

then your border as drawable/my_border:

```
//you can set the border colors, width, and which sides should have borders.
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#e2e2e2"/>
</shape>
```

if you only want a border on one/specific sides you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    //this is your textview main background
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
//this will then draw only left border with specified colour and width
<item android:left="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#e1e1e1" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. for which textview i need to apply? for both textview?

Comment: no probs, if you apply it on the left text view you can use the bottom solution of mine and simply change android:left="1dp" to read android:right="1dp" so you set a right border. that should be sufficient and it wont be neccessary to put it on both textviews. its good to know this though as you will find many situations where you need borders around views or even have to create your own buttons!

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even have a view in the middle of the `RelativeLayout`, so put the following view inside the relative layout `delivery_edit_delete_layout` after the view `delivery_edit` :

```
<View
android:id="@+id/view_separator"
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="#cfcfcf" />
```

but remember that you have to provide a fixed height for that, here I specified `30dp`, or at least provide a fixed height to the `RelativeLayout` and give this separator view a `match_parent` height.

Answer (score 0):

try this

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/delivery_edit_delete_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/divider"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_edit"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:textColor="#555555" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delivery_delete"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#555555" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**divider.xml in ur drawables**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:bottom="-2dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#cfcfcf" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

hope it works for u...